# wicd stuck on obtaining ip address after logging into windows first

Tags: 16.04, windows, internet, wicd

*I know there are many topics regarding this issue, however none of the solutions I tried helped me

**TL;DR** For some reason whenever I log into Windows 1st, I cant connect with wicd after.

As the title says wicd gets stuck on obtaining IP address after I log into windows 8.1 first.

Basically I have Windows 8.1 that I installed on top of Ubuntu 16.04 (installed Ubuntu first). Whenever I turn my PC on and log into Windows 1st, after restarting my PC and logging into Ubuntu, wicd always stucks on obtaining IP address. The way I solve this problem now is by turning PC off and logging into Ubuntu 1st.

However, if I log into Ubuntu 1st wicd connects without any problems. I can then restart and log into Windows and I will have the internet (both wired and wifi). Restarting and logging back into Ubuntu after that doesnt cause any problems neither.

Things I have tried:

1. reinstalling wicd
2. uninstalling network-manager
3. iwconfig up/down
4. sudo service network-manager restart (when I had it)
5. reinstalling wifi driver

I have both lan and wifi (TP-Link TL-WN725N driver=r8188eu)

lshw -C network output when internet works:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 11
       serial: 70:85:c2:61:44:f7
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:33 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fd500000-fd500fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: wlxc025e912cb2a
       serial: c0:25:e9:12:cb:2a
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

Please let me know if you need any other info